# how to create a soap based web services in liferay

Tags: liferay-6.2

I am new to liferay.
I want to know how to create SOAP based web-services in liferay6.2.
Please post the all steps to create a SOAP based web-services in liferay6.2.

Thanks and regard :
Manoj Kumar

Answer (score 0):

- Create a portlet plugin project
- Add a service builder configuration (service.xml)
- Run Service Builder
- Deploy

You might want to consider:

- Services (SOAP and REST) created by using Liferay's Service builder are mainly useful for persisting data in the Liferay database
- Liferay 6.2's SOAP impl. is based on Axis 2, an archaic version that only supports some deprecated SOAP style (document/literal or rpc/literal or some other combination)

Anyway, *Service Builder* is the Liferay keyword to further explore this topic.